# How do I map a single property to multiple XmlElementAttribute for serialization?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a class that I am not sure how to implement.
Not sure how to instantiate and set the Quantity choice to a particular value.
The serialization is not producing the desired output.
I am trying to have the class serialized to output

```
<aaaa>  
    <Quantity>Quantity</Quantity>  
</aaaa>
```

Where as I am expecting

```
<aaaa>  
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>  
</aaaa>  




    public class aaaa {
    private object itemField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Available", typeof(bool))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Lookup", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Quantity", typeof(string), DataType="nonNegativeInteger")]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}





private void myFunc()
{
   try {
    var myClass = new aaaa {
        Item = "Quantity"
    };

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(aaaa));
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter , Item);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```

And here is the XML from which the class was auto gen'd.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="aaaa">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="Available" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element name="Quantity"  type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                <xsd:element name="Lookup"    type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please provide more details and ask a specific question.

Comment: *"when I went to serialize"* - This does not demonstrate the specific operation you're performing.  *"it barfed"* - This does not describe the specific error you're observing.  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: You should not be using `System.Object` as the declared return type of a property - use strong types. Avoid using C# Anonymous Types too as they're kinda useless now that we have ValueTuples and Record Types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this desired output you would have to instantiate your class this way :

```
var aaaa = new aaaa();
aaaa.Item = "500";
aaaa.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.Quantity;
```

Then you would get this :

```
<aaaa xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Quantity>500</Quantity>
</aaaa>
```

Item contains the value of the element so you must make sure that the type of this object respect what's in these attributes :

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Available", typeof(bool))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Lookup", typeof(string))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Quantity", typeof(string), DataType="nonNegativeInteger")]
```

As you can see Quantity is a string and not an actual integer, using an integer would not work.

Comment: Added this to complete the code:[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType {  Quantity }
And added to class aaa
public ItemChoiceTypeTest ItemElementName ;